# Admob Banner Ads not Showing after Size Adjustment

Tags: c#, android, admob, unity-game-engine, banner

Initially I was using smart banners and could display them. Somehow the size was rather unpredictable so I tried to fix a custom size for them. Below is what I am doing now.

```
AdSize adSize = new AdSize(Screen.width, Mathf.FloorToInt(Screen.height * 0.1f));
bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, adSize, AdPosition.Bottom);
```

In the Unity Editor, I received the following debugging messages:

```
Dummy .ctor
Dummy CreateBannerView
Dummy LoadAd
```

However when I tried it on my Android phone, the banner ad simply wasn't displayed.

What have I missed?

I don't want to use smart banners.

The official link is [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start).